# Add a storyboard view as a subview of a programmatically created view

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, storyboard

I have created a special class of UIView that has certain properties, and I did so programmatically because it is usually blank but will at times contain other views.  I know that if I create a UIView programmatically I can do something like `[specialView addSubview: aView];`

My problem is that there is a UIView that I created in storyboard and I need to add that UIView as a subview on my special view.  I have connected it as a property in my ViewController but when I do the same code as above, nothing happens.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyScene"]; 
[specialView addSubview:myViewController.theViewToAdd];
```

And don't forget to give such an identifier to your scene (view controller) in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is you can add the viewcontroller as a childviewcontroller.

```
    func displayContentController(content: UIViewController) {
    addChildViewController(content)
    self.view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

To remove :

```
func hideContentController(content: UIViewController) {
    content.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    content.view.removeFromSuperview()
    content.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That UIViewController which houses the view you want may not be instantiated. So you would need to instantiate that controller and grab the view from there.